# IDW interpolation in Python in QGIS 3.4

Tags: python, qgis-3, interpolation, pyqgis-3

I have a problem with IDW interpolation. I need to use canvas extent and other attributes (I created an option with only attribute `0`, other attributes aren't working). The documentation is not very helpful.

My code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() 

layer_data = QgsInterpolator.LayerData()
layer_data.source = xlayer
layer_data.zCoordInterpolation=False
layer_data.interpolationAttribute =0
layer_data.SourceType =SourcePoints
layer_data.distanceCoefficient=2


tin_interpolator = QgsIDWInterpolator([layer_data])

export_path = r"C:\Users\Maria\Documents\miau.tif"

cos= canvas.extent()

output = QgsGridFileWriter(tin_interpolator,export_path,cos,2000,2000)
output.writeFile()

rlayer=iface.addRasterLayer(export_path, "interpolation_output")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you called it `tin_interpolator` when you want to use `QgsIDWInterpolator` :) But you need to replace the following lines:

- `layer_data.SourceType =SourcePoints` to

  `layer_data.sourceType = QgsInterpolator.SourcePoints`

---

- `layer_data.distanceCoefficient=2` to

  `tin_interpolator.setDistanceCoefficient(2)`

---

- `cos= canvas.extent()` to

  `cos = iface.mapCanvas().extent()`

---

So your final code should look something like:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
layer_data = QgsInterpolator.LayerData()
layer_data.source = layer
layer_data.zCoordInterpolation = False
layer_data.interpolationAttribute = 0
layer_data.sourceType = QgsInterpolator.SourcePoints

tin_interpolator = QgsIDWInterpolator([layer_data])
tin_interpolator.setDistanceCoefficient(2)

export_path = r"C:\Users\Maria\Documents\miau.tif"
cos = iface.mapCanvas().extent()
output = QgsGridFileWriter(tin_interpolator,export_path,cos,2000,2000)
output.writeFile()

rlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(export_path, "interpolation_output")
```